# changing style of empty diode in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuits

I'm trying to change the thickness of the outlines of an empty diode in a tikzpicture. According to the TikZ manual the option `style` should handle this, but in my case there is no difference between the two examples below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,1) to [empty diode={style={ultra thin}}] (2,1);
\draw (0,0) to [empty diode={style={ultra thick}}] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works without `circuitikz` package. but not empty diode.

Comment: yeah, but I wrote the whole circuit as a tikzpicture so I don't want to change everything because of this.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[12pt,tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,1) to [empty diode, ultra thin] (2,1);
\draw (0,0) to [empty diode, ultra thick] (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: thanks, it works now.

Comment: @zarko can you turn your comment into a response?

Comment: @AndréC, done! Thank you for encourage me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone} \usepackage{circuitikz} \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}  

\begin{document}     
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC] 
\draw (0,1) to [empty diode, ultra thin] (2,1); 
\draw (0,0) to [empty diode, ultra thick] (2,0);     
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

gives.

[image]

You should not mix syntax of `tikz` and `circuitikz` package. Regardless that `circuitikz` is based on `tikz`, its syntax is not compatible with syntax of the`Circuit Libraries` (which is inspired by the work of Massimo Redaelli, the first author of CircuiTikZ package) from the `tikz` package.

For more details see package documentation, subsection *3.1 Path-style components*, pp 25.

Comment: IMO, It would be nicer if it is possible to make the vertical bar trim the triangle tip.

Comment: @Diaa, for this you need to ask one of package's authors, since this require redesign of diode symbol. Size of the bar is accommodated to the middle of triangle lines in diode symbol (i.e., it not consider line's width). In normal circumstances is not expected that one like to have thicker lines than they default defined, where this differences is not (so) visible.

Comment: TikZ draws lines centered on their coordinates, so increasing the width causes overlap on both sides.  The easiest way to draw only in the interior is to use \clip.